# How to check whether there is any special characters present in the given string using python?

Tags: python

The prog asks me to check whether any special char like !@#... are present in the given string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function first. Use `re.search` with a pattern `[^\w\s\d]` which will match anything that is not a letter, space, digit, or underscore.

```
In [43]: def foo(string):
    ...:     return 'Valid' if not re.search('[^\w\s]', string) else 'Invalid'
    ...:
```

Now, you may call it with your strings:

```
In [44]: foo("@#example!")
Out[44]: 'Invalid'

In [45]: foo("Seemingly valid string")
Out[45]: 'Valid'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `any(x in string for x in '@#!')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.match` to do this task.

Try :

```
word = "@#example!"
import re
print ("Valid" if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", word) else "Invalid")
```

Output :

```
Invalid
```